# Android application home screen icon showing default android icon?

Tags: android, icons, homescreen

My applications are behaving oddly when deploying them on the phone. The application icon shows correctly in the applications drawer but in the home screen they show a default android icon. I think this has started happening since I updated to last android studio but I'm not sure of it. Before, everything was ok.

I have been researching this issue but could not find any info about it. Is anyone suffering from this problem? Have you found a solution?

Cheers.

Comment: Restart your phone, or remove the icon in the home screen and add it again

Comment: make sure that you place your app icon in all the drawable folders like drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi,drawable-xdpi,drawable-xxdpi, etc...

Comment: As I commented before, this was working ok previously. I have my icons added to all folders. And I'm testing with the same phone I tested before. This is happenning now for every new application I create.

Comment: unistall app and restart phone as suggested bt Mimmo, try to run same app using other IDE or other phone to cross check

Comment: I did that before asking. I could use another IDE to check though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on some devices that appear to cache the app icon. In my experience deleting the app from the device and reinstalling has always cured it.  This doesn't seem to be a problem when the app icon changes and the app is installed from Google Play, but only when installed via `adb`, so I don't believe users should see this problem.

Comment: I'm having this issue exactlye when downloading from Google play. This is why it is so problematic because I have to upload the application and then wait for the publication to check if everything went ok :(.

Comment: Have you tried doing a _Build_ > _Clean Project_ and/or deleting the `build` directory in case Android Studio isn't updating the version in the `build` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment due to low reputation, so I'm asking that did you place the icon in following folder:

```
mipmap-mdpi

mipmap-hdpi

mipmap-xhdpi

mipmap-xxhdpi
```

if not then place your icon in these folder and check.

because now launcher icon should in these folders.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I commented in another answer, this is happening to me now on new developed applications (that use the mipmap thing) and old applications taht use the drawable-xxxx thing.